# Using nuxtServerInit and API

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm using `nuxt.js` have a json file hosted on firebase with a list of products. Each product in the database is it's own object. Should I use nuxtServerInit to get all my api records in one go or should I just use axios on individual pages and get the related product when it is needed or requested?

I don't have thousands of products only about 40 of them.

Also how would I access the detail of the product pages rather than making an extra call to the API I could just get it from the store that the nuxtServerInit commits to via the action?

What is the best way to use nuxtServerInit when using get requests from an API? What is the benefit of using nuxtServerInit over single Axios requests?

Comment: use `nuxtServerInit` for SEO purposes.

Comment: Should I get all my API data from the method?

Comment: i dont know your design / layout but i would say get first like 10 products, and implement maybe an pagination. For the details page i would use `asyncData`

Comment: Ok, for the details page which is dynamic am I using async data with axios to get the record from the api or getting it from the store from the nuxtServerInit?